# Recursive Function Not Working in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, count, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to list categories with the recursive function in CI 4, but I couldn't. The code is below and the error message is below

```
public function categoryList($list, $parent = 0)
{

       $model = new BirimlerModel();
  $list = $model->findAll();
      
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ($list as $category){
         if ($category['birim_ust'] == $parent){
             echo'<li>' . $category['birim_adi'];
                 echo categoryList($list, $category['birim_id']);
             echo '</li>';
         }
     }
     echo '</ul>';
  echo categoryList($list);
}
```

Error message:

ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Yonetim\Birimler::categoryList(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\dentisthys\system\CodeIgniter.php on line 918 and at least 1 expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is the faulty line of your code. You are not passing the second `argument` here at the last line of your code.

```
 echo categoryList($list);
```

From the above line of your code

```
echo categoryList($list, $category['birim_id']);
```

I understand there should be another argument.

Comment: I did as you said but I still get the same error.

Comment: What do you get now? Any errors?

Comment: This

Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Management\Units::categoryList(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\dentisthys\system\CodeIgniter.php on line 918 and at least 1 expected

I am getting the error again.